# sed to operate on a range of lines plus a single line

Tags: sed

Let's say I have a file `file.txt`:

```
hello 
world
hi
there
this
wow
```

I know sed can operate on one line like:

`sed -n '2p' file.txt`

or a range :

`sed -n '2,4p' file.txt`

but how to operate on one specific line plus a range ?

`sed -n '1line and 4,5' file.txt` or in words print the first line and the range from 4th to 5th line ??

Comment: Attached dupe was a wrong one(it wasn't answering complete question of OP, it was answering only part of OP's question, which OP already mentioned in OP's question), so re-opened the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `sed`. This will print line which has string hello and will print lines from 2nd line to 4th line.

```
sed -n '/hello/p;2,4p' Input_file
```

OR to give single line number along with a lines range try following:

```
sed -n '1p;2,4p' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `-n` option to stop printing for all lines first. Then checking condition if line contains `/hello` then printing that line by `p` option. After that giving 2nd statement separated by `;` to print a range from 2nd line to 4th line number.